# Checking MySQL character set

Tags: mysql

I've modified my `my.cnf` file but I'm unsure how I can check to see if my character set is now set to UTF-8?  Is there a simple command or something I can run to check?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is:

```
SHOW VARIABLES;
```

Note that you also have a connection character set, table character set and column character set. `SHOW CREATE TABLE [identifier]` will be useful if you're unsure what these are set to.

Comment: or use phpmyadmin, for a graphical interface.